# i am using tab layout , in one of them i have a button , i want to change the fragment when that button is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a layout with three `TabItem` and a `ViewPager`, the tabs are working and showing , but when i want to load a new fragment , for example with a click of a button on one of those tab layouts , whatever I do, I can't change the fragment. I want to load a fragment when a button on one of my tabs is clicked, but the bellow code doesn't work

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                add(R.id.frame_layout_container,userDetailFragment).commit();
```

`replace` also dosn't work , i am a beginner in android development , can someone please help me ?

extra explanation: in one of them i have a listview , what i want is when i click on that item , i shall go to the detail about that item. here is the code in the main xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="#37548D"
            android:elevation="4dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:background="#115A91"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
            app:tabTextColor="#0A1102"
            >



            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/enter_tab"
                android:text="@string/inter_fragment"
                />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contact_tab"
            android:text="@string/fragment_contacts"
            />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/register_tab"
                android:text="@string/register_fragment"
                />



        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout_container"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        />







</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

update : this is the code of my UserDetailFragment with is a ListFragment

```
public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment {

    CallBacks callBacks;

    public ContactsFragment() { }
    ArrayList<UserObject> userObjects;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            userObjects = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent_Service.SERVICE_PAYLOAD);
            ArrayAdapter<UserObject> userObjectArrayAdapter = new UserArrayAdapter(context,0,userObjects);
            setListAdapter(userObjectArrayAdapter);
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Intent_Service.class);
        getActivity().startService(intent);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).
                registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter(Intent_Service.SERVICE_MESSAGE));
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,null);
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        UserObject userObject = userObjects.get(position);
        this.callBacks.send_user_object(userObject);
    }

    public interface CallBacks {
        public void send_user_object(UserObject userObject);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.callBacks = (CallBacks)context;
    }
}
```

and this is the code of my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ContactsFragment.CallBacks {

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    TabItem contacts;
    TabItem register;
    TabItem signIn;

//    ArashBroadCast broadcastReceiver = new ArashBroadCast(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page_drawer);
        tab_variable_initialiser();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if(tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.tab_contacts));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.main_contacts));
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.status_contacts));
                    }
                } else if(tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.tab_register));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.main_register));
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.status_register));
                    }
                } else {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.tab_signin));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.main_signin));
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.status_signin));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
//        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void tab_variable_initialiser() {
        this.tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        this.contacts = findViewById(R.id.contact_tab);
        this.register = findViewById(R.id.register_tab);
        this.signIn = findViewById(R.id.enter_tab);
        this.viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        this.pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        this.viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        this.toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public void send_user_object(UserObject userObject) {
        UserDetailFragment userDetailFragment = new UserDetailFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contact_fragment_layout,userDetailFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

if i use `R.id.contact_tab` , it works , but it dosn't replace the whole fragment , instead the `userDetailFragment` is shown bellow the list .
and i get the error : `No view found for id 0x7f080031 (arash.samandar.recyclerview_final:id/contact_tab) for fragment UserDetailFragment{e489f08 #3 id=0x7f080031}`

Answer (score 0):

You should link your `viewpager` with your `tablayout`

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

**edit**

how to style your `TabLayout`

first add your style :

```
<style name="AppTabLayoutDetail" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#b3ffffff</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

then add it to your `TabLayout`

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        ......
        style="@style/AppTabLayoutDetail"
        ......
      />
```

Don't forget to remove listener from your `tablayout` and just link it with your `pager`

Comment: its not working , i tried , it even deletes the texts on the tabs . do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Delete , what you mean ? Did you check your tablayout style? Color of the text and background settings

Comment: yes , i wrote the style myself , i'll fix the removal of text if i have to , the problem is that it dosn't work , with the method you suggested , i can't blow , inflate a fragment in my ListFragment tab . it just dosn't work . nothing happens , and your method does not help , can you be a little more specific ? do you want me to update my code ?

Comment: i updated and added my MainActivity class , and my UserDetailFragment . what i want is when i click on one of the listview items , i want a new fragment to show with the detail of that item .

Comment: you have to remove your listener on the tablayout , and also you have to define your style in your styles file and add it to to the attribute style in your widget.TabLayout  android:styles

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of practice I found the solution :
what I learned :

You have to use a FragmentPagerAdapter to handle your fragment changes. There are 3 important things:

1) remove the previous fragment .

2) call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the list of pages.

3) return POSITION_NONE in getItemPosition if it's asking for an old fragment.

Here is the practice code I used with a Left and a Right tab. and I change dynamically the fragments depending on what the user does

here is my code :

```
public class MyPager extends ViewPager {

    private MyPagerAdapter mMyPagerAdapter;

    public MyPager(Context context, FragmentActivity activity) {
        super(context);

        mMyPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        setAdapter(mMyPagerAdapter);

    }
    public void replaceLeftFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mMyPagerAdapter.replaceLeftFragment(fragment);
    }
    public void replaceRightFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mMyPagerAdapter.replaceRightFragment(fragment);
    }
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Fragment mLeftFragment;
    private Fragment mRightFragment;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return mLeftFragment;
        } else {
            return mRightFragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        final int nbLeft = (mLeftFragment == null) ? 0 : 1;
        final int nbRight = (mRightFragment == null) ? 0 : 1;
        return (nbLeft + nbRight);
    }

    public void replaceLeftFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (mLeftFragment != null) {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mLeftFragment).commit();
        }
        mLeftFragment = fragment;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void replaceRightFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (mRightFragment != null) {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mRightFragment).commit();
        }
        mRightFragment = fragment;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if ((object!=mLeftFragment) && (object!=mRightFragment)) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

}
```

Please give a thumbs up if it helped you, which I now it will.
thanks .